# "-dev package mylib-dev contains non-symlink" error when building lib using Yocto bitbake

Tags: linux, yocto, bitbake

I am trying to build Linux distribution using Yocto project, the target board is STM32MP157A-DK1 board ,I am using distribution package and meta data delivered by STMicroelectronics for OpenSTLinux.

I want to add c++ library based on cmake to my distribution.

I crated the recipe using command

```
devtool add --no-same-dir ../pass/to/mylib
```

Then build using

```
bitbake mylib
```

The build is done but I get this error by do_package_qa

```
"do_package_qa: QA Issue: -dev package mylib-dev contains non-symlink .so '/usr/lib/mylib.so' [dev-elf]"
```

what is the reason for such error and how to overcome it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Yocto Documentation](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/dev-manual/prebuilt-libraries.html#non-versioned-libraries), the cause of the problem is that my library is not versioned,  So in order to solve this problem, I should follow the procedure mentioned in [documentation](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/dev-manual/prebuilt-libraries.html#yocto-library-packaging-overview) or version my library.
so I added the following line in my CMakeLists.txt file in order to add version to mylibrary.

set_target_properties(MyLib PROPERTIES VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
SOVERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR})